# c# service on local computer started and then stopped

Tags: c#, mysql, windows-services

I am new in this staff.
I create a windows service using c# to connect to the mySQL database. when I run the service, it give me error like in picture , and without changing anything in database.
This is my code:

```
namespace WindowsService1
{
    public partial class Watcher : ServiceBase
    {
        public Watcher()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        Write();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
    }

    public void Write()
    {
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("Host=--;User=--;Password=--;Database=--;Convert Zero Datetime=True");

        connection.Open();
        var command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = " UPDATE messured-values SET belong_to = 'Doaa'";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("done");

    }
}
```

and the error as in the picture below 
Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: Does the code in `Write` throw an exception? Wrap it in a `try/catch` and see what happens.

Comment: As @DavidG indicated, you are most probably running into an exception - use try / catch or check the windows event log for the exception.

Comment: I tried to check windows event log and there is this error:
The service cannot start. MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '-values SET belong_to =' Doaa '' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you are not coding the use of the service correctly.  But this is not your main problem in this case.  It is a false positive and you still need to find the underlying error.

For a Windows Service the `OnStart` method should be used only for starting your process, not actually running any code that will do processing itself.

A Service has the following states as part of its LifeCycle

1. Running
2. Paused
3. Stopped

The OnStart method should move the service from the Stopped or Paused (if supported) status to the Running status and should return fairly quickly.

So first thing is to move the Code into a separate thread.  Even if it is just executed once.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    var task = Task.Run(() =>{
            Write();
     });
}
```

Then update your Write method to catch exceptions, use parameters, and then Log the error

```
try
{
        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("Host=--;User=--;Password=--;Database=--;Convert Zero Datetime=True"))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                command.CommandText = " UPDATE messured-values SET belong_to = @belong";
                command.Parameters.Add("@belong", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "Doaa";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //Log e.Message to a Log output file for debug purposes/
    }
```

You need to write methods to output the error to a debug log file, or similar.

Comment: Thank you, the error was related to the syntax of the query.

Comment: @Doaa Yes, like I said the error you posted was a False positive.  But please use note the code above as yours is misusing the OnStart method of the Service, and you have other errors such as not closing the Db connection, not secure against SQL Injection etc. which will cause you problems later.  If not in this code, in the next project!

Comment: yes you are right offcourse , my code not implemented in good way  but I have many problems before and I write just to try small query without close the connection.about onStart methods , inside it I call write() method , is it not good way !?

Comment: If I have tow connections, for 2 databases, from example, first connection, i will run query to bring value, then insert this value to the second database using second connection.
do u know how I can do this ?